# React Native apresenta erro quando tento emular Android

Tags: javascript, android, react, react-native

Tenho um aplicativo que dever ser testado em um emulador Android. Apos configuração ao ambiente React Native e Android(Incluindo a variável de ambiente). Não consigo executar o meu app no emuladro Android.

Mensagem derro:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando windows 10 x68
com JDK, JRE 1.8 instalados e configurado(Variavel de Ambiente)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro apresentado é relacionado a localização do JRE, o Gradle não está conseguindo encontrar o arquivo tools.jar.

Este arquivo geralmente se encontra na pasta lib dentro da pasta do JDK, observe que a sua variável está apontando para a pasta do JRE.

Modifique o path do JRE para a pasta do JDK.

Pode ser que você encontre-a em:

```
c:\Arquivos de Programa\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\lib\tools.jar
```